# How to share image and link?

Tags: swift

I have an app in witch I get a url at run time and share that link (witch works perfect ) but I also want to add an image in the same post but it doesn't show, why is this ? thanks, the code I have tried is below, when I use it I get an error "ambiguous reference to member'UIImage.init'

Thanks !

```
  if let currentURL = WebView.request?.URL
{
    let objectsToShare = [currentURL, UIImage(named: "Via-facebook")]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
class DataToShow{

    var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "Via-facebook.png")
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that Facebook no more allow to share link and image.

Comment: I tried on different platforms and none of them worked, and I do have an other app on the App Store ( in obj-c ) and I'm able to share an image on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will hide the informations because the user should not be manipulated by already setted content. So any Image and Url will be removed but will be send in the share. Just check you post on Facebook and it will display the image when iam not wrong.
Well on your code i dont see that you put in the image to the ActivityObjects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I tried sharing on different platforms and none of them worked , but the image not being in the ActivityObjects may be the problem, I tried changing the line to this: `let objectsToShare = [currentURL, UIImage(named: "Via-facebook")]` and it gives me an error any ideas as to why? thanks again